# How to use/select a MYSQL database on my desktop

Tags: database, terminal

I have a database file on my desktop that I am trying to open through my terminal.

my database is called: myDB.db

I tried using:
      mysql -u myDB.db -p

Thank you!!!

---

SOLVED for mysql! (Thank you Duffymo)

> mysql -h localhost -u  -p

```
>use [databaseName];
```

Also for sqlite you can do it this way:

```
sqlite3 [databaseName]
>.tables
```

Comment: mysql doesn't use `.db` files. That's from some OTHER database and mysql won't know what to do with it. Just because mysql is a database server doesn't mean you can throw some OTHER database's files at it and expect things to work.

Comment: I think it may be sqlite

Comment: then you'd need to install sqlite and use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the command line this way:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html

```
mysql -h localhost -u <admin user name> -p
```

I'm prompted for the admin or user password.

When I get into MySQL I specify which database I want to work with:

```
use X;
```

where X is the name of the schema I'm interested in.

At that point I can execute SQL commands.